# Full screen jumbotron with content underneath

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap frame work and using the jumbotron feature to create my header. I have a fixed navigation and want the jumbotron to be the full height and width of screen when scaled. I have content underneath the jumbotron that I want scrollable like regular. Just when someone gets to site its fullscreen jumbotron

html

```
<div class="jumbotron row">
    <header>
        <div class='navbar ........


   ... paragraph content ...      

</div>
```

css

```
.jumbotron { 
  position: relative;
  background: url('../img/pexels-photo.jpeg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: well, you have `height:100%;` what do you expect?

Comment: Well I put that in and it doesn't go to 100%, If I set the body to 100%height, I lose all scollability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

purii's answer is perfectly acceptable, however I'd opt for a slightly different approach when targeting the `jumbotron` BootStrap class:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fullheight jumbotron row">
    <header>
        <div class='navbar ........


   ... paragraph content ...      

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fullheight.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../img/pexels-photo.jpeg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height:100vh;
}
```

As you can see I placed a new `fullheight` class (can be any class name of course) within the "jumobtron" `<div>`. I then used that class name along with the `jumbotron` class as the selector for CSS styling.

The benefits of doing it this way is that it ensures that if you chose to use `<div class="jumobtron">` on another page in the future, you can still use BootStrap's default styling for this class.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. The most straight forward would be the usage of **viewport units** to scale your height. They are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) at least by IE >= 9.

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../img/pexels-photo.jpeg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height:100vh;
}
```